# Reference Many sonata admin Bundle

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

In my project I'm using two documents : User and Quizz. In fact I have Unidirectional relation between this two documents ( the user references one or more Quizzs).
In my Back end I'm using Sonata mongoDb Amin Bundle, And when i'm creating a User I want to add a Quizz to this User. It appears in the form, I add the Quizz , the quizz is created but there is no reference in the User Document.
User Document :

```
 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="\ATS\QuizzBundle\Document\Quizz", cascade={"all"})
 */ 
   protected $quizz = array();
```

And here is the UserAdmin :

```
->add('quizz', 'sonata_type_collection',array('by_reference' => false),
array('admin_code' => 'sonata.admin.quizz')) ;
```

I'm wondering where is the origin of this problem, any one can help please? thank you